# AllowHTMLAttribute on more than one element MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tinymce, modernizr

I'm trying to input two HTML texts on a website, my Model has the same attributes on both elements, but when I enter the page only one of them renders the HTMl input, what am I doing wrong? Here's the code:

Model class

```
    namespace RoyalHoliday.Models
{
    [Table("Contacts")]
    public class Contact
    {
        [Key]
        [JsonIgnore]
        public int ContactId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Orden")]
        public int Ordenado { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        [Display(Name = "Idioma")]
        public int IdiomaId { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual Idioma Idioma { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 3)]
        [Required()]
        [Display(Name = "Título")]
        public string Titulo { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        [Required()]
        [Display(Name = "Subtitulo")]
        [AllowHtml]
        public string Subtitulo { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        [Required()]
        [Display(Name = "Descripción")]
        [AllowHtml]
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here's the cshtml

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Subtitulo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Subtitulo, new { htmlAttributes = new { required = "required" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Subtitulo, "Campo de subtítulo es obligatorio", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Descripcion, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Descripcion, new { htmlAttributes = new {  required = "required" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Descripcion, "La descripción es obligatoria", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the render

[image]

**EDIT:** Here's the list of scripts on the project

[image]

**EDIT 2:** Here's the script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    (function(){

      $(function() {

          $('#Descripcion').tinymce({

            // Location of TinyMCE script
            script_url: '/Scripts/tinymce/tiny_mce.js',
            theme: "advanced",

            height: "500",
            width: "790",
            verify_html : false,
            plugins : "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount,advlist,autosave",

            // Theme options
            theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull",
            theme_advanced_buttons2: "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,image,code",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
            theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
            theme_advanced_resizing : false,

            // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
            content_css : "~/Scripts/tinymce/css/content.css",
            convert_urls : false,

            // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
            template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
            external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
            external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
            media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js"

          });



      });

    })();

</script>
```

Do you have any idea of what can be?

Comment: You have not show your scripts for attaching whatever plugin your using

Comment: And it has nothing at all to do with an `[AllowHtml]` attribute

Comment: @StephenMuecke can you help me? I've added the scripts (I'm not the initial developer of this project so I don't know how can I put two HTML inputs)

Comment: Show your script(s) for attaching the tinymce plugin to the elements (its clearly only being applied to the `Descripcion` input and not the `Subtitulo` input)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks a lot, you were right the tinymce was only applied to one element (didn't knew what was that for)

Answer (score 0):

As Stephen pointed out I needed to add the tinymce two both elements, here's the final script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    (function(){

      $(function() {

          $('#Descripcion').tinymce({

            // Location of TinyMCE script
            script_url: '/Scripts/tinymce/tiny_mce.js',
            theme: "advanced",

            height: "500",
            width: "790",
            verify_html : false,
            plugins : "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount,advlist,autosave",

            // Theme options
            theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull",
            theme_advanced_buttons2: "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,image,code",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
            theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
            theme_advanced_resizing : false,

            // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
            content_css : "~/Scripts/tinymce/css/content.css",
            convert_urls : false,

            // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
            template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
            external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
            external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
            media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js"

          });

          $('#Subtitulo').tinymce({

              // Location of TinyMCE script
              script_url: '/Scripts/tinymce/tiny_mce.js',
              theme: "advanced",

              height: "500",
              width: "790",
              verify_html: false,
              plugins: "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount,advlist,autosave",

              // Theme options
              theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull",
              theme_advanced_buttons2: "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,image,code",
              theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
              theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
              theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
              theme_advanced_resizing: false,

              // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
              content_css: "~/Scripts/tinymce/css/content.css",
              convert_urls: false,

              // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
              template_external_list_url: "lists/template_list.js",
              external_link_list_url: "lists/link_list.js",
              external_image_list_url: "lists/image_list.js",
              media_external_list_url: "lists/media_list.js"

          });

      });

    })();

</script>
```

And the render

[image]

Comment: You only need one script - `$('textarea').tinymce({ ... })` or use give the elements a class name and use that (there is no point duplicating code). And as a side note, remove the pointless `new { required = "required" }` - that does not work with jQuery client side validation.